# Is it possible to design a book cover using Gimp only?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Since I do not have and do not use Windows, I in fact, does not have Photoshop Im wondering if its possible to design a book cover using Gimp only?

Or maybe there is another useful tool |I could use to design a book cover? I know very little about graphics (I prefer programming and networks), I draw only on a paper, but now my boss wants me to transfer my hand-drawan sketch into an electronic form, as a book cover. Any ideas? Will be very grateful (I found only some youtube tutorials, but unfortunately only for Photoshop).

Comment: im confused, why did you tag this as [tag:adobe-indesign]?  Is there a reason why you are using InDesign?  Does InDesign play a role in the question?

Comment: @Matt - It is quite possible that the OP is not aware that InDesign is an application (a fair number of folks I run into equate Adobe and Photoshop, unaware that DTP and pre-press are "things", and this question is obviously "in design").

Answer (score 2):

You could technically use Paint if you wanted to produce the book cover so there shouldn't be a problem with using Gimp.  However, your question is very confusing on what your intended goal is so I will answer it in regards to going the digital route.

If you are producing a cover for a platform to be used as a thumbnail, such as iTunes, there are requirements in regards to the size associated with it:

- The book’s cover art that appears on the iBooks Store (also known
  as the marketing image) is the image delivered alongside the book
  asset and does not refer to the cover image included in the book
  asset. The pixel limit for the interior cover, as with all interior
  book images, has been increased to 3.2 million pixels.
- The book’s cover art must use RGB color mode and should be at least
  1400 pixels along the shorter axis. For best results, a good rule of
  thumb is to use an image that is a minimum of 300 dpi.
- The book’s cover art file must be a high-quality JPEG with .jpg or
  .jpeg extension or PNG with .png extension.
- The 3.2 million pixel limit on interior book images does not apply
  to the external cover/marketing image that is sent alongside the book asset.
- It is important that you do not increase the size of a smaller
  image to meet the minimum image size dimension standard. Excessively
  blurry or pixelated images will be rejected.

This section is located under Book Cover Art in the [iBooks Asset Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iBooksAssetGuide5.1Revision2.pdf)

In [Amazon's guidelines](http://s3.amazonaws.com/kindlegen/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf) under section 3.2 Cover Image Guidelines:

Kindle books must have a marketing cover image provided for use on the website detail page. The preferred format for the marketing cover is an image of 2560 pixels on the longest side and 1600 pixels on the shortest side with 350 dpi to ensure image clarity on Kindle HDX devices. The image file size should be 5MB or smaller.
If the marketing cover image size is smaller than the 2560 x 1600 recommendation, a reminder message is displayed at time of upload. Covers with less than 500 pixels on the smaller side are not displayed on the website.
If your cover image is smaller than the recommended size, Amazon strongly recommends that you create a new image that meets the size requirements. Do not stretch the image to meet the size requirements, because this may lower the image quality.
The content of the cover image must not:
• Infringe another publisher’s or artist’s copyright on the same cover.
• Mention pricing or other temporary promotional offers

[Barnes and Noble](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/help/cds2.asp?pid=8150):

- We accept the following file formats: TIFF or JPEG. Use highest jpeg
  quality setting. We will not accept PDF files or MS Word documents.
- The longest side of the digital image must be between 1,400-2,000
  pixels, with the shorter side proportional.
- Scanner resolution must be between 100-150 dpi.
- Do not send extremely high resolution scans.

That said I used what some would say are the top three players in the digital book world.  I would suggest if you are creating a digital book and the included cover inside the book should be `900px` wide and should yield around a vertical height of `1390px`.

Comment: Just for completeness, most POD (print on demand) services have very similar requirements: JPEG or PNG @300ppi (text may be added using a proprietary "cover tool" in some cases, but with limited available sizes and effects).

Comment: I agree, but as stated in my comment to the OP I am lost in the direction of the question.  If the OP can clarify what they need an answer to I'm sure I can add more to help them but they appear to have come and gone.

Answer (score 1):

Most publishers (print) want artwork in CMYK and in a PDF file. If you can manage that for your final product, you probably can use Gimp.

I would make sure you have all the details from the publsihing company. They usually provide templates with the layout (places for the ISBN and bar codes, spine width, etc.).  The author will need to submit the book to the publisher to get the spine width which is based on the number of pages, (if you're publishing in print).

If it's just a cover for something like Amazon Kindle, they have guidelines on artwork here https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A2J0TRG6OPX0VM

Hope that helps!

Comment: Gimp doesn't support CMYK, so it's no good if the printer wants a file in that colorspace. Though if you have access to Acrobat you could modify the generated pdf. I don't know if Scribus (FOSS' layout program) supports CMYK.